# How to verify accessToken in node/express using aws-amplify?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS amplify for user authentication on my front-end React app.
My React app directly communicates with amplify without any backend(node server) interaction.

I have a REST API written in node/express. I want to secure that API using amplify.

Currently, I am planning to pass the access token from my react app to my node server. But I am unable to find a way through which I can verify this token on the backend using amplify.

Does aws-amplify package provide any function in which I can pass the access token to verify it?

Something like `Auth.verifyToken(<access_token>)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such method available in official aws-amplify SDK.
After doing a lot of research I had to write my own middleware for that. This is not that difficult as it may seem but the only difficult part is to gather the right information from the huge AWS documentation.

I 've written this middleware to achieve the same, Hope this helps

```
import axios from 'axios'
import awsconfig from '../../aws-exports';

const COGNITO_URL = `https://cognito-idp.${awsconfig.aws_project_region}.amazonaws.com/`;

const authentication = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const accessToken = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

        const { data } = await axios.post(
            COGNITO_URL,
            {
                AccessToken: accessToken
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
                    "X-Amz-Target": "AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.GetUser"
                }
            }
        )

        req.user = data;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Auth failed'
        });
    }
};

export default authentication;
```

This middleware takes the authorization header and verifies the incoming accessToken using AWS Cognito REST API.

In order to get accessToken on your front-end you can do something like this:

```
const { accessToken: { jwtToken } } = await Auth.currentSession();
```

This `jwtToken` is your accessToken you can send this in your `Authorization` header and then verify this in the backend using the middleware I've written.

Comment: Thank you so much for this article. It's truly helpful you saved a huge amount of time.

Comment: For anyone using amplify v6, you can get the access token in the front end by
import { fetchAuthSession } from "aws-amplify/auth";

...

const accessToken = (await fetchAuthSession()).tokens?.accessToken?.toString();

Answer (score 5):

AWS actually has this documented pretty well. I have written a gist on a middleware I wrote to validate AWS Cognito tokens in my express.js server.

Essentially, when you create a User Pool in Amazon, AWS creates a JSON Web Key (JWK). The JWT contains a public key you can use to verify the signature of a JWT.

At a high level in Javascript:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const authToken = getJwtFromHeader(request);

// please remember to verify the "iss" claim and "exp" claim!
validateAuthToken(authToken);

// convert a jwk to a PEM for use by OpenSSL or crypto
const jwk = getJwkFromAWS();
const pem = jwkToPem(jwk);

// verify the signature of the token using the public key from AWS
await jwt.verify(authToken, pem, {algorithms: ['RS256']}, (err, decoded) =>{
  console.log('decoded', decoded);
  // TODO -- verify claims from decoded token
});
```

My GIST for a full express.js implementation:
https://gist.github.com/fourgates/92dc769468497863168417c3524e24dd

AWS Resources:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

Comment: Important: for anyone reading this, _please_ remember to verify the "iss" claim and "exp" claim! If you don't check the "iss" claim, anyone with an AWS account can create a User Pool and issue JWTs that will authenticate with your app. Sounds obvious, but in case you forget!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the aws-amplify SDK doesn't provide that functionality. For that reason, I've created an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cognito-express) to handle it.

##### How it works

[image: Authentication flow]

The package exposes:

- `authenticate`: An Express middleware that can be added to any route that needs to be authenticated against a Cognito User Pool.
- `authenticationError`: An Express error handler that takes care of any authentication errors generated by the `authenticate` middleware.
- `JWTValidator`: A class that can be instantiated to validate JWTs issued by Cognito. This is useful if you need a custom authentication and error handling logic. The `authenticate` middleware uses it internally.

##### Features included

- JWT signature verification.
- JWT claims verification.
- Verify that the token is not expired.
- Verify that the audience (aud) claim matches one of the valid
  audiences provided in the configuration.
- Verify that the issuer (iss) claim is valid for the configured user
  pool.
- Verify that the token_use claim matches one of the valid token uses
  provided in the configuration.
- Support for JWKs rotation as per described in the [JWT signing key
  rotation thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=241570).
- Ability to set custom pems for local testing without the need of
  creating a User Pool.

##### Basic usage

```
// app.js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const { authenticate, authenticationError } = require('aws-cognito-express');

const app = express();

// Add the authentication middleware.
app.use(authenticate({
  region: 'us-east-2',
  userPoolId: 'us-east-2_6IfDT7ZUq',
  tokenUse: ['id', 'access'],
  audience: ['55plsi2cl0o267lfusmgaf67pf']
}));

// Protected route.
app.get('/articles', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('JWT payload: ', req.cognito);
});

// Add the authentication error handler.
app.use(authenticationError());

module.exports = app;
```

For more advanced use cases, please check the docs [here](https://buccfer.github.io/aws-cognito-express/tutorial-01-quick-start.html).

Comment: Please don't just post some tool / package or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @Shree I just updated it. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: @StevenSiebert I just edited my answer to make it clear that aws-amplify SDK doesn't provide this at the moment. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Since 17 September 2021, we now have this repository (and associated npm package):

- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-jwt-verify
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-jwt-verify

This allows us (external node applications, usually server side web facing applications) to verify JWTs signed by AWS, such as those emitted from AWS cognito.

Specifically, as the tokens are asymmetrically signed, this verified AWS account publisher of the node package refers to the AWS published JSON Web Key Set (JWKS), promoting a degree of trust in the code we use to verify the claims contained in JWTs as they may be presented as bearer tokens to our apps.

The sample code taken from: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-jwt-verify#express (in this case it uses `express`) appears to be quite user-friendly as well:

```
import express, { Request } from 'express';
import { CognitoJwtVerifier } from 'aws-jwt-verify';


const cognitoJWTVerifier = CognitoJwtVerifier.create({
  userPoolId: 'your-user-pool-id', // mandatory, can't be overridden upon calling verify
  tokenUse: 'access',
  clientId: 'your-client-id',
});


app.get('/authenticated/route', async (req: Request & { verifiedCognitoJWT?: any }, res, next) => {
  try {
    const verifiedCognitoJWT = await cognitoJWTVerifier.verify(`${req.header('authorization')}`);
    req.verifiedCognitoJWT = verifiedCognitoJWT;

    next();
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(401).json({ statusCode: 401, message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
}, getAuthenticatedRoute);
```

Note that you can optionally call `hydrate()` to pre-fetch the JWKS before your app begins listening for HTTP connections, but omitting this call just delays the first call to `verify()` which lazily fetches them.

And of course this example can be extended with proper typings, or built into a middleware etc. as required.